# Как можно эмулировать мышь в игре с помощью C#

Tags: c#, мышь

В игре стоит защита поэтому вариант с

> mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN
>   не работает

Нужна какой то действующий рабочий пример с эмуляцией мышки.
Мне знающий человек посоветовал https://github.com/GreenBytes95/MoK
Но я не знаю как с ним работать на C#

Comment: Работа напрямую через Windows API

Comment: "Мне знающий человек посоветовал" - вам посоветовали на уровне железа обманывать комп, при чём для этого нужно купить не дешёвый чип, и ещё понять как его прошить. "Хороший совет".

Comment: C# это не тот язык, который хорошо подходит для этого. Вам нужно обходить защиту, ибо все "рабочие" примеры не будут работать.

Comment: @iluxa1810 И что вы имеет ввиду пример?

Comment: @ВасилийКристов Найти функции движения мыши в WinAPI и через P/Invoke подавать в них значения.

Comment: @nick_n_a На Алике не такой уж и дорогой. Есть аналог более удобный, ищется по словам "ss micro".

Comment: Если вопрос состоит в том, как работать через чип, то вопрос разбивается как минимум на два.  1. Нужно ли прошивать чип, если да - как прошить чип. 2. Как отправить команду на c# на этот чип.

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, вы хотите через чип, или вы хотите без чипа.

Comment: мне нужно без чипа виртуальное устройство сделать через которое подаваь команды

Comment: @ВасилийКристов https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx

Comment: @iluxa1810 а `mouse_event` это не WinAPI? Зачем вы советуете автору то, что не работает?

Comment: @Zergatul, не понимаю, как можно заблочить winapi методы в игре, если как раз винда посылает информацию о курсоре. Или я где-то не прав.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если по простому - защита перехватывает вызовы WinAPI, и смотрит откуда они вызываются. Если из "неправильного" места, тогда защита блокирует вызов оригинальной функции. Некоторые защиты игр могут встраиваться на уровне драйвера. Обойти такое очень сложно.

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

```csharp
SetCursorPos(x, y);
```

Comment: Это не работает! я же написал

Comment: Это использовали в далких 2009 годах в 2D эпоху

Comment: @ВасилийКристов а... тогда всё предельно ясно :) желаю удачи